# MySQL counting multiple columns in group by clause

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I'd like to count each distinct group being used in a group by clause. I am using this query right now:

```
SELECT language, group,  count(*) AS frequency
FROM bfs
where firstname <> ''
GROUP BY language, group
```

Which gives me result like this:

```
'Language' 'Group'                'Frequency' 
'ARABIC'   'LEBANESE'               1080 
'ARABIC'   'MUSLIM'                40963 
'ARABIC'   'MUSLIM MIDDLE EAST'      349 
'ARABIC'   'MUSLIM  NORTH AFRICAN'   549
```

What I would like is: instead of total frequency of each combination of language and group column, I'd like to know how many records of each language and group attributes are there

```
'Language' 'Group' 'Frequency' 'Language Frequency' 'Group Frequency'
'ARABIC'   'LEBANESE' 1080        42941              1080
```

Where Language Frequency represents the total number of rows with 'ARABIC' as its value; similarly Group Frequency represents the total number of rows which contains 'LEBANESE' as the group frequency.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is performance or simplicity more important for this query?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    g.language, g.`group`, g.frequency,
    gl.language_frequency, gg.group_frequency
FROM
      ( SELECT language, `group`,  COUNT(*) AS frequency
        FROM bfs
        WHERE firstname > ''
        GROUP BY language, `group`
      ) AS g
    JOIN
      ( SELECT language, COUNT(*) AS languageFrequency
        FROM bfs
        WHERE firstname > ''
        GROUP BY language
      ) AS gl
      ON gl.language = g.language
    JOIN
      ( SELECT `group`, COUNT(*) AS group_frequency
        FROM bfs
        WHERE firstname > ''
        GROUP BY `group`
      ) AS gg
      ON gg.`group`= g.`group` ;
```