# Mysql group by 2 fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to count the total number for makes found in my database

i have 3 tables

vehicle_make

```
+----+------+
| id | make |
+----+------+
|  1 | Audi |
|  2 | BMW  |
+----+------+
```

vehicle_ads

```
+----+-----------+----------+------+-----------+
| id | make_code |  model   | year | dealer_id |
+----+-----------+----------+------+-----------+
|  1 |         2 | 5 series | 2010 |        0  |
+----+-----------+----------+------+-----------+
|  2 |         2 | 3 series | 2014 |        20 |
+----+-----------+----------+------+-----------+
```

dealership

```
+----+------------+------+
| id | dealername | make |
+----+------------+------+
| 20 | bla bla    |    2 |
+----+------------+------+
```

Here is my sql query, which i tried to [modify this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065325/mysql-counting-multiple-columns-in-group-by-clause) so i can group by make and dealer_id

```
SELECT j.make AS make, j.id AS id, sum(j.count) AS count FROM 
(
    (
        SELECT v.make, sum(count+dealerCount)
        FROM 
             ( SELECT a.dealer_id, v.make AS make, a.make_code, COUNT(*) AS count
                    FROM `vehicle_make` AS v
                    JOIN `vehicle_ads` AS a
                    ON (v.id=a.make_code)
                    WHERE a.dealer_id>0
                    GROUP BY a.dealer_id, a.make_code
              ) AS g
            JOIN
              ( SELECT a.dealer_id, v.make, a.make_code, COUNT(*) AS dealerCount
                    FROM `vehicle_make` AS v
                    JOIN `vehicle_ads` AS a
                    ON (v.id=a.make_code)
                    WHERE a.dealer_id>0
                    GROUP BY a.dealer_id
              ) AS gl
              ON gl.dealer_id = g.dealer_id
            JOIN
              ( SELECT a.make_code, COUNT(*) AS makeCount
                    FROM `vehicle_make` AS v
                    JOIN `vehicle_ads` AS a
                    ON (v.id=a.make_code)
                    WHERE a.dealer_id>0
                    GROUP BY a.make_code
              ) AS gg
            ON gg.make_code=g.make_code 
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT v.make AS make, v.id AS id, COUNT(*) AS count
                    FROM `dealership` AS d
                    JOIN `vehicle_make` AS v
                    ON (v.id=d.make)
                    GROUP BY d.make
    )
) AS j GROUP BY j.make
```

Right now i get this error.

## 1052 - Column 'make' in field list is ambiguous

Output should look like this

```
+--------+----+-------+
|  make  | id | count |
+--------+----+-------+
| Audi   |  1 |   300 |
| BMW    |  2 |   150 |
| Toyota |  3 |    50 |
+--------+----+-------+
```

Basically it should get total number of makes, in dealership table, and get total number of makes in vechile_ads table (group by make and dealer_id)

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here.

**UPDATE:**
[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d228d6/1)

In the fiddle above, `NUMADS` for `BMW` should be 1 (group by `dealer_id`) and the columns returned should be `make`, `make_code`, `count` where `count` is NUMADS + NUMDEALER

Comment: In case of `union` or `union all` the number of columns selected should be same something as `select col1,col2 from table1 union select col1,col2 from table2`

Comment: Can you add what the output should look like?

Comment: I cannot see how you can derive that result set from that data set

Comment: Presumably, the `make` in the `dealership` table is a different thing than `make_id` in `vehicle_ads`; one is saying which "brand" the dealer is associated with, and the other is saying what type of car is actually being advertised.  If you're trying to find the number of car ads out there, counting the dealership makes no sense, and vice versa.  You also don't use the extra columns in the first subquery, so I'm not sure what you're trying there... Otherwise, the error you're getting is saying exactly what you're doing wrong - `UNION` is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
SELECT make.id,
       make.make,
       ( IFNULL(ads.cout, 0) + IFNULL(deal.cout, 0) ) AS cout
FROM   vehicle_make make
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT make_code                 AS id,
                               Count(DISTINCT dealer_id) AS cout
                        FROM   vehicle_ads
                        GROUP  BY make_code) ads
                    ON make.id = ads.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT make     AS id,
                               Count(*) AS cout
                        FROM   dealership
                        WHERE  make IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP  BY make) deal
                    ON make.id = deal.id;
```

Subquery `ads` will give you the `count` of `distinct dealers` who posted ads for a `make` from `vehicle_ads` table. Subquery `deal` will give you the count of makes from `dealership` table. in the end, Using `left outer join` join `vehicle_make` table to `ads` and `deal` so that result should contain all `id` and `make` and add the counts coming from both the subqueries to get desired result.

[Sample SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d228d6/63)

Note : in your sql fiddle replace count(*) with count(distinct dealer_id) will give you what you desired. check [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d228d6/65).

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the count from two tales.  Here is a way:

```
select vh.make, sum(numads) as numads, sum(numdealer) as numdealer
from ((select make_code as model_id, count(*) as numads, 0 as numdealer
       from vehicle_ads
       group by model_id
      ) union all
      (select make as model_id, 0, count(*)
       from dealership
       group by model_id
      )
     ) c join
     vehicle_make vm
     on c.model_id = vm.id
group by vh.make;
```

As a note:  You should name columns consistently in your database.  Having `make` be a string column in one table and an integer foreign key reference in another leads to confusion.  I would suggest calling all the foreign key references to `vehicle_make.id` something like `model_id`.

Comment: i want `numads` to be grouped by `dealer_id` to count how many dealers have for example at least 1 BMW. and `numads` should be added to `numdealer`. Thanks for the tip on naming my columns

Comment: @user2636556 - except then you're counting two different, unrelated things in the same column.  One is a count of cars, the other businesses.  What is it you think you're counting in such a case?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse so in my `dealership` table i have a list of new and used dealers. in my `vehicle_ads` i have listings of cars posted by the dealers. In a list of car makes `BMW` should show the number of used car dealers posting a BMW and the number of new BMW dealers (regardless if they have a posting or not)

Comment: @user2636556 - Yeah, that's two different things.  How do you know how many "new" BMW Dealerships you have, vs how many ads for BMW cars you have?  That needs to be in two different columns.  Or, think about it this way - this week, there are 4 ads and 1 new dealer.  Next week, there are 3 ads and _two_ new dealers.  The person running the report sees the numbers haven't changed and says "you have no new competition"...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse  oh, i just want to make a list of makes (BMW's) with the total number. when someone clicks on BMW (using href) it will go to another page and show the break down (make, model, dealer / individual and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Does this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a306/27) give the output you require?

```
SELECT vm.`make`,
       vm.`make_code`,
       IFNULL(subq.`num_ads`, 0) AS `count`
FROM `vehicle_make` vm
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ad.`make_code`, COUNT(*) AS `num_ads`
 FROM
 (SELECT *
  FROM `vehicle_ads`
  GROUP BY `make_code`, `dealer_id`) ad
 GROUP BY ad.`make_code`) subq
ON subq.`make_code` = vm.`id`
```

Comment: close. but still getting wrong results. `http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a306/1` BMW is correct (2). but Aston Martin should be 1, and Audi (2) and Austin is correct at 0

Comment: Ah I see! So you just want to count the number of distinct "dealers with ads" for each make. Have updated the SQL in my answer - please check if it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you are simply declaring 2 columns named make in you joins. the first one is:

```
SELECT a.dealer_id, v.make AS make, a.make_code, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `vehicle_make` AS v       ^------------------------------- this field called make
JOIN `vehicle_ads` AS a
ON (v.id=a.make_code)
WHERE a.dealer_id>0
GROUP BY a.dealer_id, a.make_code
```

and the second one is here:

```
SELECT v.make AS make, v.id AS id, COUNT(*) AS count
                   ^------------------------------------ this field also called make
FROM `dealership` AS d
JOIN `vehicle_make` AS v
ON (v.id=d.make)
GROUP BY d.make
```

just rename them and run your code.. in general it looks just fine :)